# MooTols & jQuery

Tags: jquery, framework, mootools

Скажите , если использовать 2 фреймворка в одном проекте, не будет ли конфликтовать?(Странно, что нет метки для MooTols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто поставить оба на страницу, то будут. Но jQuery может делать так:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict(); // теперь работает через j(...)
```

Ну, или просто все писать через jQuery(...).

Answer (score 1):

насколько я знаю, ещё можно подключить к проекту файл со скриптом и весь скрипт поместить в подобную конструкцию:

```
 `(function($){
  //Ваш код
 })(jQuery)`
```